# Force on an electron in a given orbital

Tags: quantum-chemistry, orbitals, atoms

I was wondering whether there is any quantum mechanical  equation to describe the force on a given electron in a given orbital of an atom (lets say, for the simplest case, for hydrogen atom). Also if it exists then what is the use of effective nuclear charge?

Comment: The force concept exists in the Bohr's model. However, it is more "natural" to talk of angular momentum (recall it is related to force) in the quantum world which have no classical analogs. It is better to keep the ideas of Bohr model separate from QM.

Comment: In QM model, there exist the potential in the Schroedinger  equation, that is in direct relation to the electrostatic force.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. If you think that your electrons go in circles then get it out of your head expeditiously.

Comment: No I don't think of electron moving in a circle.

Comment: Also asked on Physics. Please don’t cross post like that.

Comment: Well, electron described by any orbital can be found in virtually any place in atom so why you ask about a "given" orbital?

Comment: An orbital is not an orbit. Also for hydrogen atom an electron in its lowest energy state resides in 1s orbital.